# What is NULL, does it need to be declared?

Tags: c++

In this snippet I found [here](http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Hash_table/Simple_example) for a simple C++ hash everywhere there is a NULL I get a

> NULL was not declared in this scope.

I'm using MinGW compiler g++.  My guess is that NULL is not a reserved keyword?  How could I determine the version of gcc and look at a reference list for C++ keywords?

This list [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keywords) states that NULL is not a keyword.

```
int main()
  {
  }

const int TABLE_SIZE = 128;
class HashEntry 
  {
  private:
    int key;
    int value;
  public:
    HashEntry(int key, int value) 
      {
      this->key = key;
      this->value = value;
      }
    int getKey() 
      {
      return key;
      }
    int getValue() 
      {
      return value;
      }
  }; 
class HashMap 
  {
  private:
    HashEntry **table;
  public:
    HashMap() 
      {
      table = new HashEntry*[TABLE_SIZE];
      for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++) table[i] = NULL;
      }
    int get(int key) 
      {
      int hash = (key % TABLE_SIZE);
      while (table[hash] != NULL && table[hash]->getKey() != key) hash = (hash + 1) % TABLE_SIZE;
      if (table[hash] == NULL)return -1;
      else return table[hash]->getValue();
      }
    void put(int key, int value) 
      {
      int hash = (key % TABLE_SIZE);
      while (table[hash] != NULL && table[hash]->getKey() != key)
      hash = (hash + 1) % TABLE_SIZE;
      if (table[hash] != NULL) delete table[hash];
      table[hash] = new HashEntry(key, value);
      }     
    ~HashMap() 
      {
      for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
        if (table[i] != NULL) delete table[i];
      delete[] table;
      }
};
```

Comment: I know what NULL is used for - to set a value that is not used, I think this is more of a syntax issue.

Comment: semantics rather than syntax perhaps...

Comment: You don't need to check for non-nullness when invoking `delete`.

Comment: Just use 0, or `nullptr` if your compiler supports it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NULL` is a standard *macro* declared in `stddef.h`. You need to include `stddef.h` (or `cstddef`) in order to use `NULL`.

You can always use `0` in place of `NULL`, if you don't want to include anything.

Comment: For C++ the include is `cstddef`

Comment: you mean a #define...can I just write #define NULL 0

Comment: @Chris Aaker: You can, but this will most certainly case conflicts when you eventually begin including standard headers. It is highly unlikely that you will get away without doing it eventually.

Comment: @K-ballo: Albeit deprecated, `stddef.h` is still available in C++.

Comment: @ChrisAaker: Yes and no. As long as your file doesn't include a standard header that defines the macro, it's allowed. Since C++ allows one header to include another, however, that means it's only allowed if you don't include *any* standard headers.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned elsewhere `NULL` is defined in `stddef.h`, and probably also in some other system header files (I have not checked this recently).

If you're using only C++ and not including anything then you can write:

```
#define NULL 0
```

at the top of your file and it will work as expected.

In newer C++0x or C++11 compilers have a keyword `nullptr` which should be used instead of `NULL` or `0` where pointers are concerned.